# How to update two MySQL tables through AJAX in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery-ui

I am new here. I have been trying to make a simple application where user can drag and drop the items from a couple of tables to a cart and they get added to his own que (or table) on a click (there are total 3 tables). I have read almost 50 blog posts and watched about 10 You-Tube videos for this so far but I didn't understand how I can update my all three tables once user says "add them to my que". I can understand only JS, JQ and a little Ajax. I am learning though.

you can look this up at my page:
[Here](http://ageetey.com/queuing/manage.php)
(in the demo Green table is user's own table and orange ones are the ones that he can choose items from.) I want my user to drag and drop rows from orange table and on clicking "add to my que" those rows should be deleted from orange tables and gets added to his table (green table).

index.php

```
    <!--Drag Area-->
    <div id="panel1">
        <p class="text-muted">Drag in this area</p>
      </div>

    <!--Add to my list button-->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="color:green">Add to my que</button>


<!--User's own table where the records should be added after he clicks add to my list-->
   <table>
<?php
        <!--MySQL Query for fetching the records-->

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT r_no, gen_date, item, qty, due_date FROM request WHERE buyer_no=1001 ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 5");

    echo ("<thead><tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Due Date</th>
            </tr></thead>");
    echo ("<tbody>");
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) ) {
        echo '<tr><td>';
        echo(htmlentities($row[2]));
        echo("</td><td>");
        echo(htmlentities($row[3]));
        echo("</td><td>");
        echo(htmlentities($row[4]));
        echo("</td></tr>\n");
    }
    echo ("</tbody>");
    ?>    
    </table>
    <!-- two tables with <tr> class wow. the user will take the items from here and drag them to drag area-->
        <table id="table2">

<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT r_no, gen_date, item, qty, due_date FROM request WHERE buyer_no=2001 ORDER BY r_no DESC LIMIT 5");

    echo ("<thead><tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Due Date</th>
            </tr></thead>");
    echo ("<tbody>");
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) ) {
        echo '<tr class="wow"><td>';
        echo(htmlentities($row[2]));
        echo("</td><td>");
        echo(htmlentities($row[3]));
        echo("</td><td>");
        echo(htmlentities($row[4]));
        echo("</td></tr>\n");
    }
    echo ("</tbody>");
    ?>    
    </table>




<table>

<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT r_no, gen_date, item, qty, due_date FROM request WHERE buyer_no=3001 ORDER BY r_no DESC LIMIT 5");

        echo ("<thead><tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Due Date</th>
            </tr></thead>");
    echo ("<tbody>");
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) ) {
        echo '<tr class="wow"><td>';
        echo(htmlentities($row[2]));
        echo("</td><td>");
        echo(htmlentities($row[3]));
        echo("</td><td>");
        echo(htmlentities($row[4]));
        echo("</td></tr>\n");
    }
    echo ("</tbody>");
    ?>    
    </table>
```

.js file

```
    <!--JS file-->

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wow').draggable({containment: 'document', revert: true,
    start: function(){
        contents = $(this).html();
        }
        });

$('#panel1').droppable({hoverClass: 'border', accept: '.wow',
drop: function(){
    $('#panel1').append(contents + '<br/>');
}
});
});
```

Comment: I'm not very clear on what you're asking, are you asking how to update MySQL from PHP, or how to make the Ajax call to PHP to cause the update?

Comment: @Nunners: I have just added little more information to my question. I hope this helps.Yes, I am asking how to transfer the selected requests from other two tables and and add them to the user's own table and delete the same records from the other two tables. How to update these MySQL tables with the help of PHP, JS, JQ and Ajax (whatever is required).

Answer (score 1):

You must be having a primary key in the table. Assuming  "**item**" is your **primary key**.

Give a unique id to the user table.

```
<table id="userTable"> ....
```

Give your "Add to my que" button an id.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="addToQue">Add to que</button>
```

When "Add to my que" button is pressed make an ajax call to a PHP script say "update.php". Send all the "item" values in post request.
jQuery code:

```
$("#addToQue").click(function() {
    var all_tds = $('#userTable tr td:first-child');  //Since item is the first td in tr
    var items="";
    all_tds.each(function(){ 
       items = items +"-"+ this.value //concatenate all the values of item using -
    })
    $.ajax({
       url : "http://yourdomain.com/update.php",
       type : "POST",
       data : "toupdate=" + items,   //send the concatenated value
       success: function(data) {
           location.reload();          //reload the webpage
    });

});
```

In update.php use php `split()` function to split the values of `$_POST['toupdate']`. It will give you individual value of `item` and then perform the sql update queries using the same. I hope you can write SQL queries once you are provided with the values of item.